# App freezes after extending Google Plus login Activity

Tags: android, google-plus

Am using the Google+ login feature in my app. The Login functionality is in my `LoginActivity`, and the logout functionality is called from another activity, an Activity containing Fragments. To be able to call the logout method, the Activity containing the Fragments extends the Login Activity(else the app crashes). These methods are in the Login Activity:

```
// Initializing google plus api client (from onCreate method of Login Activity)
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this).addApi(Plus.API)
            .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN).build();

 //Called when a connection is successful
 public void onConnected(Bundle arg0) {
    mSignInClicked = false;
    Toast.makeText(this, "User is connected!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    //Get user's information
    getProfileInformation();

    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), UtilityActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);

}
```

When I run the app, the Toast is never dismissed.When I comment out the toast and run the app again, none of the widgets respond. Am thinking the app stays in an `onConnected` state?.

I don't know why this happening, but am suspecting it's because am calling the `onCreate` method or the `onConnected` method twice?

The call to signout is being made from the `onOptionsItemsSelected` method of the Activity containing the Fragments like this:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    switch (id) {
        case R.id.action_settings:
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Settings selected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return true;
        case R.id.action_logout:
            signOutFromGooglePlus();
            return true;
        case R.id.action_revoke_access:
            revokeGplusAccess();
            return true;
    }
```

Method called when the signin button is clicked:

```
private void signInWithGooglePlus() {
    if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting()) {
        mSignInClicked = true;
        resolveSignInError();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code snippets are incomplete. Where do you call the connect method for the google client api for example?

Comment: It's initialized in the onCreate method.Clicking the sign in button just connects you.

Comment: If clicking the button connects you, then it means you have code in the button that calls the connect method. So, post the button click listener code and lets see what it's doing. Also, it would be helpful if you'd set a breakpoint in onConnected and report whether it is actually getting called multiple times.

Comment: I think adding that code introduces redundancy to the question, but I've added it anyway.I'll give the other suggestion a try too

Comment: So, again, you've yet to post code where you call the connect() method of the googleApiClient. If that code exists, you should post it. If not, you need to fix that problem and determine what is calling onConnected().

Comment: The only redundant information that code snippet introduces is that your button click listener does not do what you say it does (which I suspected) - that you don't fully understand what's going on.

Here's a suggestion, post ALL your code on pastepin, then link to it here. I'm not going to keep trying to guess at which method contains the code with your problem.

Comment: Check it out http://pastebin.com/K5dJeJKc

Comment: Ok, I looked at the pastebin. While there are some things that could be done better, I didn't notice any obvious major issues other than you calling mGoogleApiClient.connect() from onStart(). This may or may not be an issue. How are you launching the LoginActivity?

Comment: LoginActivity is the launcher activity

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78559/discussion-between-iheanyi-and-ojonugwa-ochalifu).

Answer (score 0):

You mention that the issue is occurring in UtilityActivity, which is launched by LoginActivity in onConnect().

Your likely issue (without seeing the code in UtilityActivity) is that UtilityActivity does not have a reference to the connected GooogleApiClient from LoginActivity. So, while you have a valid connection in LoginActivity, you do not in UtilityActivity. Remember, extending LoginActivity doesn't mean you share its fields. It's more like sharing code w/o having to copy/paste.

There are several options on how to proceed - pass a copy of mGoogleApiClient in the Intent that launches UtilityActivity, make the activity that controls login/logout a service that all your other activities can use, pass only the information that UtilityActivity needs in an Intent when launched, have each Activity manage their GoogleApiClient connections directly...